# Excel workbook not closing Python Excel COM

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, win32com, office-automation

The below code excel application is opening but not closing for some reason.Help me on this.

```
import win32com.client as win32
Filepath = r"C:\New_Technicals\Excel_devp_Test\Model_Variable_Pah_v1.xlsx"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible= True
excelApl= excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filepath)

ECU_OutSgls_ls =['xxx','yyy','zzz']
Path_ECU_OutSgls =[]

i=0
while i < len(ECU_OutSgls_ls):
c = excelApl.Worksheets("aaa").Range("A1:A100").Find(ECU_OutSgls_ls[i])
Path_ECU_OutSgls.append( excelApl.Worksheets("aaa").Range(c.Address).Offset(1,2))
i= i+1


excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Have you tried `excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close(True)`?

Comment: No luck. Its still not closing..

Answer (score 0):

In the following line of code:

```
excelApl= excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filepath)
```

The `Application` property is not required. You already have an Application instance returned from the `EnsureDispatch` function.

The [Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) method opens a workbook and returns a `Workbook` object that represents the opened workbook. So, you could should look like that instead:

```
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filepath)
```

And when you need to close the workbook you may simply call the `Close` method:

```
workbook.Close
```